# How do I let onClick() read from my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files `index.html` and `index.js`. When I fill the text fields in the form and click the button, it should redirect to `index.js`. How do I achieve that?

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="head">Hello</h1>
    <input type="email" id="email"></input>
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" id="pass"></input>
    <br><br>
    <button>Click</button>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
if (document.getElementById("email").nodeValue==document.getElementById("pass").nodeValue){
        alert("You are allowed");
}
```

**EDIT:** I can do this simply by creating the function inside the `<script>` tag itself and then calling the function inside `onClick` in the `<button>` tag. But instead, I want the `onClick` to call my `index.js` script which will perform the backend stuff

Comment: You haven't bound your button to an eventhandler. What makes you think your button will call any function at all? You'll need to do some very basic reading about adding `onclick` events to buttons.

Comment: Can you tell me your purpose? you might try to do something wrong, I think.

Comment: I've checked on some tutorials in youtube, where they've defined a function in `<script type="text\javascript"> function_name(){...} </script>`  tag in the html page itself, to handle the action and then they wrote `<button onClick="function_name()">Click</button>`. But I don't want that. What I want is that `onClick` it should redirect to `index.js`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit? I'm having a hard time understand what you're trying to achieve when this button is pressed. If you could elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do I think we can help you out. Also please clarify what you mean by redirect to index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare this function in index.js

```
function handleClick() {
  if (
    document.getElementById('email').nodeValue ===
    document.getElementById('pass').nodeValue
  ) {
    alert('You are allowed');
  }
}
```

call it on button click

```
<button onclick="handleClick()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Ah yes, I always wanted the `html` to do the frontend part and `javascript` to do the backend part. I thought `onclick="function_name()"` worked only if you created the function in the html script.

Answer (score 0):

you should link the html file to the javascript file using

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="(your file location)"></script>
```

then add event listeners to listen to the button click using

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("button-id").addEventListener('click', yourFunction)
});

function yourFunction(){
    //your code here
}
```

also add an `id` to the button so you can add the event listener to it

```html
<button id="button-id">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EventListener to bind button click event to a function.

```js
   
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
    
        if (document.getElementById("email").value==document.getElementById("pass").value){
        alert("You are allowed");
        
}

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="head">Hello</h1>
            <input type="email" id="email"></input>
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" id="pass"></input>
            <br><br>
            <button>Click</button>  
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always call your script inside js only. It is bad practice to call scripts in the html structure. I gave you an example of calling script logic and accessing a component using `querySelector()`.

```js
var form_button = document.querySelector('.thisisbutton');
var email_input = document.querySelector("#email");
var pass_input = document.querySelector("#pass");

form_button.onclick = function() {
if (email_input.value == pass_input.value){
        alert("You are allowed");
}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="head">Hello</h1>
    <input type="email" id="email">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" id="pass">
    <br><br>
    <button class="thisisbutton">Click</button>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the js file in your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

then you should add onclick event on your button

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

then in index.js you should add the function

```
function myFunction(){
    //your logic goes here
}
```